# How to avoid global temporary table in oracle pl/sql

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I am using the following FUNCTION to check the duplicate values based on the given string in array (po_System_arr).  The following are the description for the input parameters

1. array will send two values (one is pi_SysArr(i).PrdID and another one is pi_SysArr(i).sysVal)
2. String in "pi_ValueString"
3. System IID  in  pi_system_iid (nothing but customer ID)

For that i am using a global temporary table (GTT_CR_PROCESS .

Is there any other way of checking the duplicate value without storing in GTT ---  Table Script

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE GTT_CR_PROCESS
(SYSTEM_IID NUMBER , SYSTEM_STRING VARCHAR2(500))  
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
```

**FUNCTION**

```
FUNCTION Fnc_ChkSystem_Value (pi_SysArr            in po_System_arr,
                          pi_ValueString        VARCHAR2,
                          pi_system_iid         ms_card.SYSTEM_IID%type                          
                          ) 
RETURN NUMBER 
IS
    v_cnt         NUMBER := 0;
    v_cnt1        NUMBER := 0;
    v_ArrCNT      NUMBER := 0;

    ChkDup        Varchar2(1) :='N';
    nCount          NUMBER:=0;
    nStringCount    NUMBER:=0;
    vSystem_iid ms_card.SYSTEM_IID%TYPE;
    v_AttribIID     NUMBER;
BEGIN   

IF pi_SysArr IS NOT NULL and pi_SysArr.COUNT>0 THEN
    v_ArrCNT := pi_SysArr.COUNT;

    -- Loop through the array of attributes
    FOR i in pi_SysArr.FIRST..pi_SysArr.LAST 
    LOOP
            v_AttribIID := get_ProductTypeID(pi_ProductType => pi_SysArr(i).PrdType,
                                             pi_ProductId => pi_SysArr(i).PrdID);

            SELECT  COUNT(1) INTO nCount
             from  hk_system_values  HSV
            WHERE hsv.value_iid = v_AttribIID 
              AND  UPPER(hsv.system_value) =  UPPER(pi_SysArr(i).sysVal)
              AND hsv.STATUS = 0;

              If nCount > 0 Then    
                    FOR RS IN (SELECT SYSTEM_IID   from  hk_system_values  hsv 
                                WHERE hsv.value_iid = v_AttribIID 
                                AND  UPPER(hsv.system_value) =  UPPER(pi_SysArr(i).sysVal)
                                AND hsv.STATUS = 0)
                    LOOP    

                            MERGE INTO GTT_CR_PROCESS CR
                            USING dual
                            ON (CR.SYSTEM_IID = RS.SYSTEM_IID)
                            WHEN MATCHED THEN
                                UPDATE
                                   SET CR.SYSTEM_STRING = CR.SYSTEM_STRING||UPPER(pi_SysArr(i).sysVal)
                             WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                                INSERT
                                    (SYSTEM_IID, SYSTEM_STRING)
                                VALUES
                                    (RS.SYSTEM_IID,
                                    UPPER(pi_SysArr(i).sysVal)
                                     );
                             ChkDup := 'Y';
                    END LOOP;
              ELSE              -
                 EXIT;
                 ChkDup := 'N';
              END IF;
    END LOOP;   


    if ChkDup = 'Y' Then 
            SELECT COUNT(1),max(SYSTEM_IID) 
             INTO nStringCount, vSystem_iid 
             FROM GTT_CR_PROCESS 
             WHERE SYSTEM_STRING = pi_ValueString;

            COMMIT;

            IF nStringCount > 0 then         
                If nStringCount = 1 and vSystem_iid = pi_system_iid Then         

                    RETURN 0;
                else 
                    RETURN 1;
                end if;
            ELSE 
                RETURN 0;
            END IF;
    ELSE            -- No Duplicate found
            RETURN 0;
    END IF;
ELSE 
    RETURN 0;            
END IF;

END;
```

From the above code , the desired results are coming correctly. But i want to avoid GTT , is there any other way?.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your motivation for wanting to avoid a GTT?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have millions of rows in the table, otherwise you will blow up the PGA for your session, I would declare an in memory collection like this:

```
 TYPE t_chkdup IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32);
 l_chkdup t_chkdup
```

Put the system value into the collection like this after your condition:

```
l_chkdup(i) := UPPER(hsv.system_value); -- or whatever is the unique value here
```

Then do the following:

```
for j in l_chkdup.first..l_chkdup.last loop
 if l_chkdup.exists(j) then
 ...... do something
 end if;
end loop;
```

You will find this runs extremely fast at the cost of using more CPU and memory though.